# setting balloon tooltip for an image

Tags: silverlight, tooltip

how to set balloon tooltip for  an image in silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ToolTipService like so:

```
<Image>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <!-- Any XAML Content Here -->
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Image>
```